# Comparing characters in C reads as pointer and integer

Tags: c, comparison

I am trying to compare a character in an `if` statement and then print the value of its position in the alphabet.

My code reads:

```
char a = 'a';
int value = 0;
if(a == "A" || a == "a"){
    value = 1;
}else if...
```

When compiling I get the error: `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

```
if(a == "A" || a == "a"){
     ^
```

I get that characters are stored as ASCII values in **C** which means I could probably use the integer value of the characters instead and that would work, but I was wondering why this doesn't?

Comment: ansci, that venerable standard for things that may be strings *or* characters. C ansci literals are spelled as `'x"` to indicate that duality.

Answer (score 7):

Use single quotes:

```
if(a == 'A' || a == 'a' ){
```

Double quotes are for string literals. When you compare `a == "A"`, the chracter `a` is compared to a pointer (i.e. the string literal used in an expression yields a pointer to its first element). Hence, the diagnostic issued by compiler. It's same with `"a"`.

Answer (score 3):

`"a"` is not a character but a string literal.

Strings are essentially arrays of characters ended by a `'\0'` (Null character).

You need to use `'a'` instead.

Moreover, There was no need of using so many *if-else*s

you could do it with a very short piece of code:

```
if(a >= 'a')
   a-=('a'-'A');

value = a - 'A' + 1;
```

Comment: Note that if the code set was for a mainframe using EBCDIC, the gap between 'a' and 'z' is much bigger than 25; there are other characters tucked in the midst of the alphabet.  However, for most practical purposes, what you suggest is fine, and well spotted on the 26-way repeat that wasn't actually shown.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of varaible `a` and how looks its initializer

```
char a = 'a';
```

and compare the initializer with literals used in the if statement

```
if(a == "A" || a == "a"){
```

As it is visible to the naked eye `'a'` and `"a"` look differently. And indeed they have different types.

`'a'` is a character literal that has type `int`.

`"a"` is a string literal that has type `char[2]` because it consists from two characters `'a'` and the terminating zero `'\0'`

You can imagine the definition of the string literal like

```
char string_literal_a[2] = { 'a', '\0' };
```

There is no implicit conversion from an array (string literal) to type int (character literal).

Thus in this statement

```
if(a == "A" || a == "a"){
```

character arrays that is string literals "A" and "a" are converted to pointers to their first elements that is to expressions of type `char *` and the compiler issues a warning because it suspects that you are trying to do something wrong at least not what you want actually to do..

A correct condition can be written the following way

```
if ( a == 'A' || a == 'a' ) {
```

You could use an array in the condition but only as an expression for example with the subscript operator if the result of the expression will be a character. For example

```
if ( a == "A"[0] || a == "a"[0] ){
```

or

```
if ( a == *"A" || a == *"a" ){
```

However though these records are correct they confuse readers. So it is better to use the record with character literals

```
if ( a == 'A' || a == 'a' ) {
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax :

```
char a = 'a';
int value = 0;
if(a == 'A' || a == 'a')
{
    value = 1;
}
```

The error is resulting from checking equality between a character('x') and a "string" .

Instead,you may declare `a` as `char[]` (string) and then use the `strcmp(str1,str2)` function to get return int in `value` as :

```
value = strcmp(str1,str2);
```

This function return values that are as follows:

if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.

if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.

if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char a;
int value = 0;
printf("enter the character ");
scanf("%c",&a);

if(a == 'A' || a == 'a'){
    value = 1;
    printf("hi");
}
else {
    printf("hello");
}

}
```

Comment: How/why does your code solve OP's problem? What have you done to fix it?